# Vim Function Execute Command Delayed Till End

Tags: vim

I try to write a simple function in my `.vimrc`, accessable by a mapping.
This function should use the [YankRing](https://github.com/vim-scripts/YankRing.vim) plugin. Therefore it first open a window with the *YankRing* buffer, if not open yet. I could confirm the functionality of each part in that function, but as soon as I define any command after the window open, it will be executed first and just after all, the window is opened. In fact it seems like something happen, cause the buffer status (name, line, col, ...) appears in the command line, but the window with the buffer itself does not open.

Here is a minimal example, using a `sleep` as following command, that leads to the delay of the window opening:

```
function! s:foo()
    execute('YRShow 0') " Opens the YankRing window, if not already open.
    echo 'bar' " Just to have some visual reference.
    sleep 3 " Show the delay of the window open and the echo message.
endfunction
```

**Observed behaviour:**
First, the command line gets this buffer status information content. Immediately afterwards, the `echo` message is shown. Then after the 3s delay, the window is opened.

**Expected behaviour:**
Open the window. Show the message and wait 3s.

---

Anybody who understand what is happening here? For my function the user needs to watch the window content, before he can interact.

Thanks!

Comment: there are people here who understand that way better than me, but as far as I am concerned, the vim buffer system is event driven. So the "window" open command is queued and you need to look at `:h autocmds`

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo Which auto-command u would say help here?

Comment: depending on your usecase, `BufNew` or `BufWinEnter` for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some plugin mappings and commands are *asynchronous*. Vim has an event system; cp. `:help autocommand`. In that case, you have to hook into the appropriate events (`:help autocmd-events`). For plugins, these often are `BufNew` or `FileType`.

With mappings, these are just like typed commands, and inserted in an input buffer. To asynchronously execute mappings *after* any other pending commands, the `feedkeys()` function can be used. Do this only when necessary, as its use interferes with macro recording and command repeats!

I had a brief look at the YankRing code. The `:YRShow` functionality seems to be straightforward, synchronous code. The effect you are experiencing may be that the contents aren't yet drawn while your function is executing. You can enfore a screen update via `:redraw`, before the `:sleep` command.

Comment: So not every creation of a new buffer is handled asynchronous but the redrawing is?

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo: Correct. You can create a buffer and immediately fill it, like this: `new | put! =\"new buffer\"`

Comment: of course ... luckely it is not that i use something like that every day (`:sp | e ...`) would be a dumb question then...

Comment: Thank u very much. The `redraw` helps here!